# Rayleigh quotient simplification using inner products and norms (quick question)

Tags: linear-algebra

I was wondering if this simplification of the Rayleigh quotient is correct, or if I am unknowingly making a simplification or multiplication error. If so, why do we not define the equation like this or as <l(x),x>, where ||x|| = 1?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sake of generality, it is easier to use a function that takes any `x` than to use a function that requires `|x|=1`. It is your decision to handle the complexity inside the function or outside it.

These manipulations are making the assumptions that L is [homogeneous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function) of degree one, e.g. a linear map. And that the properties of the inner product `<a x, y> = a<x, y>`, `<x, a y> = a<x, y>` for a scalar `a`, and defining `||x||^2=<x,x>`, and the standard some algebra of real numbers.